# How to get only statusCode of url and don't get it's data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to play a remote url with audioplayers plugin
but I want to check only status code of url before play.

I am new to flutter so I try with http.get(url) and also try/catch statement .

and if url statusCode is 404 it is immediately give me 404
but the problem is that if the url is correct , http.get ; recieve all data and after that show me the statusCode = 200 and this check takes a long time.
is there any way to only check status code of a get method in http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the endpoint supports [HEAD requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) (`http.head`).

> The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that are returned if the specified resource would be requested with an HTTP GET method. Such a request can be done before deciding to download a large resource to save bandwidth, for example.

Comment: thanks for answer but how to use it in flutter app ?

Comment: You said you're doing `http.get` now. Couldn't you change it to `http.head` instead?

Comment: excuse me , that was because , I am new to programming